# BigInteger conversion among Java and Javascript

Tags: javascript, java

I'm developing an encryption/decryption algorithm among a javascript client and a java server.

As far so good, but I have some issues to obtain the same values in BigInteger when I convert string.

Currently, I'm using the JSBN library ([http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/jsbn.js](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/%7Etjw/jsbn/jsbn.js)) in javascript to produce BigIntegers values, whereas I'm using the java.math.BigInteger class for Java.

For instance, if I try to convert "abcd1234" string in Javascript the web-browser console gives in output `BigInteger {0: 197988916, 1: 10, t: 2, s: 0}`, whereas in java I obtain `2882343476` as results.

Java Code:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
...

BigInteger x = new BigInteger("abcd1234",16)
log.debug("BigInteger Value {}", x);
//prints 2882343476
```

Javascript Code

```
const b1=  "abcd1234";
x = new BigInteger(b1, 16)    //BigInteger is the JSBN constructor
console.log(x) // prints BigInteger {0: 197988916, 1: 10, t: 2, s: 0}
```

Is there a way to harmonize the conversion among java and javascript? Is there something that I' missing?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Please add the relevant code where you create the `BigNumber` instances.

Comment: please include the code you used to produce `BigInteger {0: 197988916, 1: 10, t: 2, s: 0}` as well as the one used in Java to get the number `2882343476`

Comment: I added the snippet code that I use to generate the results. Thank you.

Comment: You should be able to use `console.log(x.toString())` to print the JSBN BigInteger as a decimal number, but I got `TypeError: this.toRadix is not a function`.

Comment: You are right, I obtain the same value (2882343476). So, If I have to apply some operation to these values (like as modpow), Can I use the x variable as it is or I have to apply the Tostring before?

Comment: If you take the value 197988916 and convert it to hex you get 'bcd1234', so the Javascript JSBN library seems to be dropping the first digit of 'a' when performing `new BigInteger`.

Comment: Suggest using BigInt and the '0x' prefix when converting from Hex to Decimal.  Ie, `BigInt('0xabcd1234')` will return `2882343476n`.

Comment: You might want to get another library (if at all, because there's a well-supported [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt#Browser_compatibility) object built into all major browsers), because the library uses methods that aren't implemented (`this.toRadix()`) and who knows what else is missing/not working correctly.

Comment: `console.log(x.toString(16))` logs `abcd1234` so the number should work as expected and the `197988916` is only part of its internal state.

Comment: @Andreas good observation.  It appears that the Javascript JSBN library internal format is little endian, and the `10` represents the hex `a`, with `t` likely representing the number of elements that form the entire value.  Thus, their internal format represents the complete value of `abcd1234`, but again as you noted, BigInt should be considered as a strong alternative.